# Beginner phyton coder here, why is my function not working properly?

Tags: python, function, raw-input

`number = raw_input("Enter a number.")`

`def function(number):
  if number % 9 == 0:
   print 9
  else:
   print number % 9`

I get the following when trying to run it:

`Enter a number.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 1, in <module>
    number = raw_input("Enter a number.")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line`

What's up with that?

Comment: Using python 2 btw

Comment: Please use Python 3, if you're learning it shouldn't make any difference. That said, please provide a [mcve]. Your code as it stands could probably be shortened. BTW: I guess the problem lies in how you execute it, for some reason no input seems to be available.

Answer (score 0):

`raw input` converts your input to string. You should convert it to int in order to work with it as a number:

```
number = int(raw_input("Enter a number."))
```

Comment: That's true, but it's not going to cause the EOF error he's seeing.

Comment: @abarnert, yes, you are right. I think EOF error is caused by some syntax issue before the line: `number = raw_input("Enter a number.")`

Comment: It wouldn't be a syntax issue. And I doubt his code is doing anything like `sys.stdin.close()`. More likely it's something about the way he's trying to run this, although I'm not sure what would do that.

Comment: well thats actually line one, so there it couldn't be caused by anything before it. im trying to make a code that takes in input from the user then calculates its digital root, as a sort of practice.

Comment: What do you mean by command line? Sorry,  I'm only just learning about coding